# Firestore crashes retrieving class, asks for empty constructor, but already has one

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

This line:

```
ProjectMap m = document.toObject(ProjectMap.class);
```

Generates the error:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dockdogs.lorecoords, PID: 5633
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class com.dockdogs.lorecoords.preferences.MapPreference$Bubble does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped (found in field 'preferences.mapBubble')
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java:54)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:749)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:189)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(CustomClassMapper.java:54)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:778)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:189)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(CustomClassMapper.java:54)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:770)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:100)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:183)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:116)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:161)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:97)
at com.dockdogs.lorecoords.SaveSystem$26.onComplete(SaveSystem.java:488)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

ProjectMap just looks like:

```
public class ProjectMap implements Serializable {
    public int height=0;
    public int width=0;
    public String id = "";
    public int scaleRatio = 1; //FOR ZOOMING THE MAP IN AND OUT
    public String mapTitle, mapPath; //map path = image path
    public boolean ISCURRENT = false; //the map that's currently being used by the user
    public ArrayList<MapEvent> mapEvents = new ArrayList<MapEvent>();
    private MapPreference preferences = new MapPreference();

}
```

... and MapPreferences looks like:

```
public class MapPreference implements Serializable {
    //Controls scale for map bitmap
    public  float minScaleX = 0.50f;
    public  float maxScaleX = 8f;
    public  float minScaleY = 0.50f;
    public  float maxScaleY = 8f;
    //end controls for scaling map bitmap


    public Dagger mapDagger = new Dagger();

    public Bubble mapBubble = new Bubble();


    public  boolean useGridLines = true;

    public  int gridCols = 0;
    public  int gridRows = 0;

    public MapPreference() {
    }


    public  void setGridRows(int gridRows) { this.gridRows = gridRows; }
    public  void setGridCols(int gridCols) { this.gridCols = gridCols; }

    //will the user have grid lines on their map?
    public  void setUseGridLines(boolean useGridLines) { this.useGridLines = useGridLines; }

    public  boolean GetUseGridLines() { return useGridLines; }

    public  int GetGridCols(){
        return gridCols;
    }
    public  int GetGridRows(){
        return gridRows;
    }

    public  float GetMinScaleX(){
        return minScaleX;
    }
    public  float GetMinScaleY(){
        return minScaleY;
    }
    public  float GetMaxScaleX(){
        return maxScaleX;
    }
    public  float GetMaxScaleY(){
        return maxScaleY;
    }
    //TODO: add a preferences page for these options
    public  void SetMinScaleX(float _minScaleX){
        minScaleX = _minScaleX;
    }
    public  void SetMinScaleY(float _minScaleY){
        minScaleY = _minScaleY;
    }
    public  void SetMaxScaleX(float _maxScaleX){
        maxScaleX = _maxScaleX;
    }
    public  void SetMaxScaleY(float _maxScaleY){
        maxScaleY = _maxScaleY;
    }


    public class Dagger implements Serializable  {
        public  float minScaleX = 0.75f;
        public  float maxScaleX = 1f;
        public  float minScaleY = 0.75f;
        public  float maxScaleY = 1f;
        public  float GetMinScaleX(){
            return minScaleX;
        }
        public  float GetMinScaleY(){
            return minScaleY;
        }
        public  float GetMaxScaleX(){
            return maxScaleX;
        }
        public  float GetMaxScaleY(){
            return maxScaleY;
        }
        //TODO: add a preferences page for these options
        public  void SetMinScaleX(float _minScaleX){
            minScaleX = _minScaleX;
        }
        public  void SetMinScaleY(float _minScaleY){
            minScaleY = _minScaleY;
        }
        public  void SetMaxScaleX(float _maxScaleX){
            maxScaleX = _maxScaleX;
        }
        public  void SetMaxScaleY(float _maxScaleY){
            maxScaleY = _maxScaleY;
        }

        public Dagger(){

        }
    }

    public class Bubble implements Serializable {
        public  float minScaleX = 0.75f;
        public  float maxScaleX = 1f;
        public  float minScaleY = 0.75f;
        public  float maxScaleY = 1f;
        public  float GetMinScaleX(){
            return minScaleX;
        }
        public  float GetMinScaleY(){
            return minScaleY;
        }
        public  float GetMaxScaleX(){
            return maxScaleX;
        }
        public  float GetMaxScaleY(){
            return maxScaleY;
        }
        //TODO: add a preferences page for these options
        public  void SetMinScaleX(float _minScaleX){
            minScaleX = _minScaleX;
        }
        public  void SetMinScaleY(float _minScaleY){
            minScaleY = _minScaleY;
        }
        public  void SetMaxScaleX(float _maxScaleX){
            maxScaleX = _maxScaleX;
        }
        public  void SetMaxScaleY(float _maxScaleY){
            maxScaleY = _maxScaleY;
        }

        public Bubble() {

        }
    }

}
```

I wonder if the floats are failing to retrieve properly with Firestore, but if that's true I'm not sure what I can do about it.

ALSO THIS ISN'T A DUPLICATE QUESTION BECAUSE THE CLASS ALREADY HAS AN EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR AND IT *STILL* THROWS THE ERROR.

Comment: Hey Adam. Did you get anywhere with this? Did you see my answer below, and did you have a chance to try that?

Comment: Hey Frank. Yeah, I was able to make these inner classes static and that's what did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some of these classes are inner classes of others. In that case, you also need to mark the inner class(es) as `static`. Without that the default constructor will require an implicit `outer` parameter that Firestore can't populate for you.

So:

```
static public class Bubble ...
```

Also see (for the Realtime Database, but the logic is the same):

- [JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338402/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found/34339036#34339036)
- [ANDROID FirebaseDatabase: Unable to save object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703001/android-firebasedatabase-unable-to-save-object/40706064#40706064)